# how to load a Master/Detail flow from a recycle view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, master-detail

The issue i have is that if i leave the adapter as an inner class of the `MainActivity`.I have no issues, it loads properly. If I move it out to a separate java file, then instead of populating the detail view, it launches the details activity.

Constructor

```
public MoviesAdapter(MovieListActivity activity, List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items, boolean twoPane) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mValues = items;
    mTwoPane = twoPane;
}
```

This is how I load the details view. its in an `onClick()` event.

```
 if (mTwoPane) {
         Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
         arguments.putString(MovieDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
         MovieDetailFragment fragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
         fragment.setArguments(arguments);
         mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
                  .commit();
 } else {
         Context context = v.getContext();
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra(MovieDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

         context.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Is this common functionality or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks ok so far, maybe you should add more code in order to spot the error

Comment: This is nothing more than the standard Master/Detail starter code that gets created when you load the project. All i did was pass MainListActivity and mTwoPane to the constructor. I just cant see why it doesnt want to work.